# Why do those two high(64bx64b) functions give different results?

Tags: c++, hpc, intrinsics, avx2, bmi

```
static __inline__ uint64_t mulhilo64(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t* hip) {
        __uint128_t product = ((__uint128_t)a)*((__uint128_t)b);
        *hip = product>>64;
        return (uint64_t)product;
}
```

I am trying to write following above using MULX intrinsics on AVX2 (more specifically [BMI2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI2_.28Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_2.29)). But they do not give the same results.

```
static __inline__ uint64_t mulhilo64(uint64_t  a, uint64_t b, uint64_t *c){
     return _mulx_u64(a, b, &c);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple test case and the result for each implementation ?

Comment: The first function is the part of a very long code. I just replaced it with 2nd function, nothing else. Do you think that they should be the same, too?

Comment: I see one probable mistake in the second function (see answer below) - I'm just trying to throw together a simple test case to see if I can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this function could be wrong:

```
static __inline__ uint64_t mulhilo64(uint64_t  a, uint64_t b, uint64_t *c){
     return _mulx_u64(a, b, &c);
}
```

It should probably be:

```
static __inline__ uint64_t mulhilo64(uint64_t  a, uint64_t b, uint64_t *c){
     return _mulx_u64(a, b, c);
}                        // ^
```

Note that compiling with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) helps to catch simple mistakes like this.